# Retrieving data from multiple tables with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

1. debtors

   - `debtorid`
   - `name`
   - `inactive`
2. rfnwagon

   - `rfnwagonid`
   - `dumpid`
   - `customerid`
   - `allocationdate`

`debtorid` has 2 values 21 and 22:

- 21 means customer
- 22 means dump

I want to display whole `rfnwagon` rows but instead of using `dumpid=21` and `customer_id=22` , I want to use the names from table `debtor`. I tried this but failed:

```
SELECT 
    rfnwag.rfn_wagon_id,
    debtor.name,
    debtor.name,
    rfnwag.no_of_wagons,
    rfnwag.order_id,
    rfnwag.product_id,
    rfnwag.destination,
    rfnwag.allocation_date      
FROM rfn_wagon_allocation as rfnwag,
        debtors_master as debtor
WHERE rfnwag.customer_id=debtor.debtor_no AND rfnwag.dump_id=debtor.debtor_no"
```

Comment: in debtors table we are having names both dump and customer in name column

Answer (score 0):

I have a difficult time to understand completely what you are asking for, but I don't see any `JOIN` here, which is needed when you use multiple table. Take a look at this example, maybe it's what you need : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: There is a join, it just doesn't use SQL-92 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this will never be true:

```
debtor.debtor_no=debtor.name
```

So remove it from your WHERE clause.

What exactly do you mean by 'without success'? No rows? too many rows? incorrect rows?

Comment: yeah changed... even though not working.... see the query i edited in the question

Comment: The query in the question has not changed and you still haven't described 'not working'

Comment: OK I see the query has now changed. The query you have now implies that customer_id and dump_id in the rfnwag table must have identical values, which does not make sense. Can you describe 'not working' please.

Comment: thanQ all for responding.... the above query doesn't reach my requirement... modified in code and database... i got it now

Comment: For all the people who might be searching the internet for an answer to this question, it would be nice to post your answer.